# Python call from root directory

Tags: python, call

I got a python file: convert.py with the comment line like this:

```
# To use, from the root directory call

python src/data/convert.py SRCDIR DESTDIR
```

Could someone tell me how to call from the root directory?

Comment: I think just `cd` to parent directory of `src` will be fine.

Comment: It just tells you the relative path if you are in the directory where you extracted it. If you did `tar xf pack.tar.gz` and it created `pack-0.1`. and you then did `cd pack-0.1` you are now in the package's root directory. Generally, software doesn't actually care where you are when you run it. This is just a simple newbie-friendly convention to make it easy to find the main executable within the package.